# How can I avoid a partial http response flush of large JSF views?

Tags: jsf, render, facelets

Today I've spend several hours reproducing a very strange UI behavior in our web application using JSF facelets: **In some cases the UI was partially rendered in the web browser before the server side really finished rendering the whole view.**

In the end it all came down to an JSF view with a large number of elements – in my case items of a submenu. There seems to be some threshold that triggers a **partial flush** of the response.

Here is a minimized example that visually demonstrates that effect:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="de" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <style>
        td {
            vertical-align: top;
        }
    </style>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h1>EURNEU-10056</h1>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ol>
                    <ui:repeat value="#{bean.strings(10)}" var="str">
                        <li><h:outputText value="#{str}" /></li>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </ol>
                <h:outputText value="#{bean.delay(2000)}" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <ol>
                    <ui:repeat value="#{bean.strings(10)}" var="str">
                        <li><h:outputText value="#{str}" /></li>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </ol>
                <h:outputText value="#{bean.delay(2000)}" />
            </td>
            <td><ol>
                    <ui:repeat value="#{bean.strings(10)}" var="str">
                        <li><h:outputText value="#{str}" /></li>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </ol>
                <h:outputText value="#{bean.delay(2000)}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</h:body>
</html>
```

That simple view uses the following bean to generate a certain amount of strings and adds some **artificial delays** into the rendering of **2000ms** after each of the 3 columns.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public List<String> strings(int count) {
        List<String> all = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            all.add(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        }
        return all;
    }

    public String delay(int delay) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // NOP;
        }
        return String.format("This string has been delayed for %d ms!", delay);
    }

}
```

The browsers shows the following phases while processing the request:

[image: partial rendering]
[image: another partial rendering]
[image: final rendering]

If I lower the amount of strings used while generating the view the response is only flushed at the very end of the render phase.

**Is there anything I can do to avoid that partial rendering?** (other than lowering the number of elements)

PS: We are using JBoss EAP v7.0.9 as a server. The application itself is quite complex.

Comment: That's no strange behavior. That's buffered output. If you have a 3-hours running process which outputs info-lines, you will like to get the lines before the end of the process. What if your output will be 17MB or 100MB. Who has to buffer it to not do partial output?

Comment: We have that flush effect with 32kB of HTML code... and it relates to the number of elements in the JSF view... not the output size for the HTML.

Comment: But the principle remains. Maybe, the JSF controls do some flush or force it.

Comment: Sure... but is there any setting I could tweak? BufferSize somewhere? I'm still looking for the relevant component / setting that causes that effect. Otherwise I'd have to remodel the menu in our UI. The effect is small in most cases... but some pages take about 10s for the full render phase and users are quite confused seeing partially loaded pages.

Comment: 10s!!! That's no dialog speed....
In glassfish  'server-config' - 'HTTP Service' you find the 32k buffer.
Or 'server-config' - 'Network Config' - 'Protocols' - 'http-listener1' - 'HTTP'

Comment: Performance is not the topic of this question... but I'll look into that buffer size. Although I still don't believe its the 32kB... we generate much larger pages that are flushed at the very end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned our that explizit defining of Facelets buffer-size in web.xml solves that problem.

```
<!-- We raise the buffer size to avoid partial rendering of complex pages. -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_BUFFER_SIZE</param-name>
    <param-value>1024000</param-value>
</context-param>
```

That setting and the structure of the generated HTML define the very moment, the browser starts to render the response. In our case the menu was already renderable and showed much earlier than expected.